# Why is my function checking for English apps returning True for non-English apps?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

I'm currently doing an exercise in a guided project on dataquest.io in Jupyter Notebook. My goal is to write a function that checks if the characters in a given string each have an ASCII number of over 127, and if the string has more than three of these, to return False.

[Github link to entire code](https://github.com/mollycg/dataquest/blob/master/Basics.ipynb) - problematic function located in Cell 20

I've tried Restart and Run All in the kernel of my Jupyter Notebook which has helped debug in the past but not this time. I've also looked at the solution for this exercise and my code is literally the same. Yet, my code is returning True for an obviously non-English app name.

```
def is_english(string):
    non_ascii = 0

    for c in string:
        char = ord(c)
        if char > 127:
            non_ascii += 1

        if non_ascii > 3:
            return False
        else:
            return True
print(is_english('爱奇艺PPS -《欢乐颂2》电视剧热播'))
print(is_english('Instachat '))
```

Output:
True
True

Expected results were:
False
True

I theorize maybe something in the larger project is an issue, as my code matches the [solution code](https://github.com/dataquestio/solutions/blob/master/Mission350Solutions.ipynb). I just can't get a grasp on what is happening. Thank you from a beginner!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your if/else: both paths return, so you are always returning after checking the first character.

You could fix this by returning True outside the for loop, so the loop goes over every character before returning  True:

```
def is_english(string):
    non_ascii = 0

    for c in string:
        char = ord(c)
        if char > 127:
            non_ascii += 1

        if non_ascii > 3:
            return False

    return True

print(is_english('爱奇艺PPS -《欢乐颂2》电视剧热播'))
print(is_english('Instachat '))
```

The linked solution is correct, and matches yours in all but indentation! If you look at the solution indentations, you can see their if/else is done after the loop finishes.

Comment: That solution fixed it right up! Thanks for getting me un-stuck.